# Passing primitive type as a reference

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for a way to pass a primitive value as a reference. The only way I found was to wrap the primitive value (boolean) with a typescript class. 
In my example I have

```
export class LoadingStateWrapper {
    value: boolean
}
```

This allows child component to change the `isLoading` value in parent component without having to define `@Output` parameter.
The only problem I have with this that I need to access the value through the class and perform null checks

```
let isLoading : LoadingStateWrapper;
if(isLoading.value){ -- trying to access .value of null
    //Do something
}
```

Is there a better way to pass primitive values by reference in typescript?
Or perhaps is there a way to override class comparator that would allow me to do something like this, but in fact it would null check the `value` and then check whether it's `false` or `true`?

```
let isLoading : LoadingStateWrapper;
if(isLoading){
     //Do something
}
```

Comment: Using an `@Output` parameter on the child component may seem like extra work now for this simple case, but I highly recommend using it in general rather than sharing state directly between components. It will be much more maintainable in the long run. See [this article](https://blog.angulartraining.com/component-architecture-with-angular-6f7bc9165443) for more details on the benefits.

Comment: FWIW `LoadingStateWrapper` doesn't need to be a `class`; you can make it an `interface` and get an instance of it with a plain js object like `{value: true}`; classes are a bit heavy for your use case.